# Set default project folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, espressif-idf

I'm using ESP-IDF extension for Visual Studio Code. How to set default project folder?
[image]

Comment: 1) what is your screenshot supposed to demonstrate? What about that UI isn't working for you? 2) As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)